# Android page crashing during image download

Tags: java, android

I am an extreme Android / Java newbie, working on my first android app.

I have a page that downloads data from a php/mySQL page and displays it on a screen layout. The data will contain certain fields; title, summary, photo, etc. The "photo" field is a URL to an image stored online.

When the photo link field is empty, the page seems to work fine. When the image is quite a small image, the page seems to work fine. But when the image is a larger file size, the app crashes.

My full code for this page is shown below, as I dont have an idea of where the issue might be with this code!

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class DetailScreen extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
DownloadImageTask d;
ImageView imageView;
int tab,position;

ImageView detail_image;
TextView detail_head;
TextView detail_disc;
TextView detail_date;
TextView detail_detail;
TextView detail_url;

Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("imageBitmap",imageBitmap);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        imageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageBitmap");
    }

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        tab = bundle.getInt(BackEnd.TAB);
        position = bundle.getInt(BackEnd.POSITION);
    }
}

void setValues()
{

    JSONArray RawData = (tab == 0) ? BackEnd.news : BackEnd.events;
    JSONObject data = null;

    try {
        data = (JSONObject) RawData.get(position);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        assert data != null;
        if(imageBitmap == null) {
            d = new DownloadImageTask(detail_image);
            d.execute((String) data.get("photograph"));
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Image");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    d.cancel(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        detail_head.setText((String) data.get("title"));
        detail_disc.setText((String) data.get((tab==0)?"summary":"location"));
        detail_date.setText((String) data.get("date"));
        detail_detail.setText(Html.fromHtml((String) data.get("details")));
        if (tab == 0) {
            final String url = (String) data.get("url");
            detail_url.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.urlMessage));
            detail_url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView t = (TextView) v;
                    t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            View view = getView();
            if(view != null) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_url);
                textView.setText("");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionBarCustom);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new Page4();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    detail_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_image);
    if(imageBitmap != null)
        detail_image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    detail_head = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_head);
    detail_disc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_disc);
    detail_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_date);
    detail_detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_detail);
    detail_url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_url);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_screen, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView t=(TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionText);
     t.setText("Details");
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
    setValues();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    relativeLayout.removeView(imageView);
}

class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageBitmap = result;
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone lend any thoughts on this problem, or see any issues with my code above?

Crash logs:

```
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 25137936-byte allocation.
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm: "AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=15 RUNNABLE
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x44106838 self=0x5fcb1a80
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=6538 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1606718640
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 101296084 23520127 71 ) utm=7 stm=2 core=1
10-15 16:59:35.436 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at com.DetailScreen$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DetailScreen.java:198)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at com.DetailScreen$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DetailScreen.java:188)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-15 16:59:35.441 6137-6538/com I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-15 16:59:35.446 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-15 16:59:35.446 6137-6538/com D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
10-15 16:59:35.446 6137-6538/com W/dalvikvm: threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b7c700)
10-15 16:59:35.446 6137-6146/com I/MotionRecognitionManager:   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
10-15 16:59:35.446 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.DetailScreen$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DetailScreen.java:198)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.DetailScreen$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DetailScreen.java:188)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
10-15 16:59:35.451 6137-6538/com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com I/MotionRecognitionManager:   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com I/MotionRecognitionManager:   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-15 16:59:35.456 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-15 16:59:35.461 6137-6146/com I/MotionRecognitionManager:   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
10-15 16:59:35.461 6137-6146/com D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-15 16:59:42.706 6137-6137/com I/Choreographer: Skipped 422 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-15 16:59:43.536 6137-6137/com D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44128b10 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44128b10 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.setValues(DetailScreen.java:95)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.onResume(DetailScreen.java:179)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-15 16:59:43.566 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{441be848 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{441be848 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.setValues(DetailScreen.java:95)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.onResume(DetailScreen.java:179)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-15 16:59:43.576 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44252ad8 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44252ad8 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.setValues(DetailScreen.java:95)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.onResume(DetailScreen.java:179)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-15 16:59:43.586 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{442e5b90 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{442e5b90 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.setValues(DetailScreen.java:95)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.onResume(DetailScreen.java:179)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-15 16:59:43.591 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4437be38 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4437be38 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.setValues(DetailScreen.java:95)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.DetailScreen.onResume(DetailScreen.java:179)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-15 16:59:43.596 6137-6137/com E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know that the php/mySQL part is all working fine. It does just seem to be this page on some images, that the app will crash while the loading spinner is spinning. And the only thing I can see that might be the cause is when the photo is a larger size.

Comment: Please can you post the logcat report

Comment: can your call show progress dialog inside Async task onpostCreate method ? and also post your crash stack trace.

Comment: did you solved?and can you give link of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Out of memory error.I guess you are downloading a large image.
I prefer you to use [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library.Its awesome and easy to use.
This library downloads images and puts in the cache of device.If you want more details how to use please feel free to write.

Comment: agreed, looks like you're allocating a 25mb bitmap in memory, this is bad.  You'll need to download the image directly to disk and then load the image of disk into memory using BitmapFactory to shrink the size.

Comment: The "big" image that crashes the app is only 420kb in size? It is 3000px x 2000px, and 420kb.

Comment: 25137936 bytes = 25 mb.
check your log
" Out of memory on a 25137936-byte allocation."

Comment: It seems that adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" solves this problem. Can you comment if this is a legitimate way to solve this?

Comment: @Richard using `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` or `android:largeHeap="true"` are not considered to be an Ideal solution.

Comment: @nuridinselimko I have past experience with UIL, I agree with you its a good library but it also causes OOM. I would rather suggest [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) Image Management Library from **Facebook**. Its a great library for managing and downloading image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this crash is memory management related, as others have noted.

I have found that this can be handled by adding an attribute:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

as an activity tag in manifests.

Can anyone comment whether this seems like this is a legitimate way to solve this crashing problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when you are downloading images and there is no memory left which was allotted to your app after downloading some images. There are various Image Loading Libraries which make your work easier : [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) etc.

1. I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.
2. Fresco has `SimpleDraweeView` as custom image view which supports `Rounded Corners and Circles` [link](http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html#_) and supports Animated(.gif, .webp) as well as Normal Images(.jpg, .png).
3. Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

You Can increase the Memory allotted to your application by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest.

**Note :** Increasing `heap` for your application doesn't considered to be a ideal solution.

Here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html